# Same getters and setters in 2 child classes..?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I'm not that good OO design .. so please bear with me..

I have Class A,  And 2 classes which extend A. But both of them have same fields.. So what is better, to have getter / setters in A or to have same getter / setters in both child classes.. Or is there a better a way to do this..?

this is what i have done (mock)..

```
 class A{

    private int x;

    protected A(int x){
    this.x = x;
    }

    public static A createA(id a, int x){
    switch(a){
    case 0: 
    return new C(x);
    break;
    //so on

    }


    public int getX(){
    return x;
   }

    }
```

Thanks..

Comment: If they are exactly the same, and will be the same for all subclasses of A, you should move it to A to avoid code duplication.

Comment: When asking questions about code, it's best to show the code you have questions about.

Comment: @assylias .. I thought of making a **factory pattern** (i don't if thats pattern name).. just make static methods to create these objects and make class A's constructor protected.. should i go on and do it..?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder .. i will add it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the classes

If those properties are a property of A then yes, 
if it's just chance they have the same properties then no.

Basicly the question you need to ask yourself is, will there ever be a class that extends A that doesn't need those properties.

If the answer is no, put them on A,

If the answer is yes, keep them on the sub-classes, 
or create another abstract class in between those 2 subclasses, having these 2 properties.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your classes are `A` (the parent) and `B` and `C` (the children). You say that `B` and `C` have some fields that are the same.

Ask yourself: If you had another class `D`, child of `A`, would it have those fields too regardless of its specific functionality?

- If the answer is yes, then the existence of these fields in both subclasses is definitely not a coincidence, so you should probably define them in `A`, because it means that they have these members precisely because they inherit from `A`.
- If the answer is no, the existence of these fields in the subclasses may or may not be a coincidence. So, you should ask yourself: Even if `D` doesn't have these fields, does their existence in both `B` and `C` look more than just a coincidence? Do these classes share something that `D`, another child of `A`, simply doesn't happen to share?

  - If yes, then consider a new class `E` that extends `A`, with `E` defining these common members and then make `B` and `C` children of `E` instead of `A`.
  - If not (if it looks to you like just a coincidence), then leave your structure as it is. Or consider an interface instead.